# Code changes in one of the angular is not being reflected in UI

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on an open source hospital management project which is using angular version 7 , asp.net core 3 and sql server. Angular part is inside wwwroot folder. I am able to add new module and able to change code in other component like app.module.ts  but in one component I am not able to change the code. I have patient-basic-info.html file where I wanted to add new patient registration field but it's not displaying that field in the UI(browser). I commented some existing code part but that commented code is still executing. I did ng build again then also could not able to do it. Same project in my friends pc is working fine.

[image: Image of patient-basic-info.html in which i commented dialysis patient field code and just below the commented code i am adding special notes field]
[image: i am expecting special notes field added and dialysis field is not displayed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something with the cache? try ctrl+shift+r

Look if your code is running on localhost and if you are viewing it that way or some remote in other environment. Inspect the element and search for it in the project in case if there is any other place with similiar code.

Comment: Thank you now it is resolved the problem was cacheing